# How to insert a colon between a number and a quote?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Source:

```
9981"TVHeadend HTTP server (web interface)"
```

and add a colon between to make python dictionaries!

But these are registered known IP address and too many to do one at a time!

I tried replacing the same find and adding the `:` but it replaced the number with the regex code!

Not ever sure if my code was correct!

Also I want to find the first double quote as you can see each line has two!

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Not a duplicate of a **_Reference_** !!

Comment: \d{4}(.*?)\" this is am using now, it finds but also find if numbers are at the end.  I don't mind if I can't do a replace all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+\K(?=")`
- Replace with: `:`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+             # 1 or more digits
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=")           # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double quote after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much!  really appreciated Toto.  I will soon learn more about regex!

Comment: @KevyTeky: You're welcome, glad it helps. You'll find usefull info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Thank you again Toto... I will definitely learn these time saving tips!